# App running different process is displayed several times in running apps list

Tags: android

My app creates some different process to do some tasks in background (Services).

I discovered that this comsumes less memory.

The problem is that the app is displayed several times in the running tasks list (and I don't know why, due to other apps that are running some process are displayed once).

How to do to get displayed only once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're confusing Processes and Threads. They are not the same thing. It sounds like you're using multiple Processes and comparing it with apps that use multiple Threads. It is likely that if your app is using multiple Processes it will show up in the running tasks list more than once, whereas apps that use multiple Threads will not.

Have a look at [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for more information. It isn't often you really need multiple Processes, but the need for multiple Threads is much more common.